# Velocity can't retreive field from pojo

Tags: java, velocity

I have velocity template, some method which merge template and POJO into text. I checked in debugger and all data is filled everywhere properly. My problem is that velocity can get only one field (queueName), but the rest can't. Why is that?

Template:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Environment: ${environment}</h3>

        <div>
            #if ($monitoredQueues.size() > 0)
            <table>
                #foreach( $monitoredQueue in $monitoredQueues )
                #set( $queueName = ${monitoredQueue.QueueName})
                #set( $crMsgCount = ${monitoredQueue.CurrentMessagesCount})
                #set( $prMsgCount = ${monitoredQueue.PreviousMessagesCount})
                #set( $prCheckTime = ${monitoredQueue.PreviousCheckTime})
                #set( $prEmailTime = ${monitoredQueue.PreviousEmailSentTime})
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Queue name: ${queueName}</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Current messages count: ${crMsgCount}</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Previous messages count: $!{prMsgCount}</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Previous check time: $!{prCheckTime}</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Previous email sent time: $!{prEmailTime}</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                #end
            </table>
            #end
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my POJO

```
@Data //lombok annotation generates getters, setters, hash and equals
@Builder //lombok annotation generates builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MonitoredQueue {

    private Integer id;
    private String queueName;
    private Integer currentMessageCount;
    private Integer previousMessageCount;
    private LocalDateTime previousCheckDate;
    private LocalDateTime previousEmailSentDate;
    private String createdBy;
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    private String modifiedBy;
    private LocalDateTime modificationDate;
}
```

Merging method

```
public String mergeTemplateIntoEmailText(List<MonitoredQueue> monitoredQueues, String environment) {
        velocityEngine.init();
        Template mailTemplate = velocityEngine.getTemplate(EMAIL_TEMPLATE);
        VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
        velocityContext.put(ENVIRONMENT, environment);
        velocityContext.put(MONITORED_QUEUE, monitoredQueues);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        mailTemplate.merge(velocityContext, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    }
```

And this is the result:

```
Environment: test

Queue name: XXXX Current messages count: $crMsgCount Previous messages count: $prMsgCount Previous check time: $prCheckTime Previous email sent time: $prEmailTime
```

I resolved my problem, by changing template. Velocity somehow loose context somewhere in deep level of html tree. Don't know why.

Comment: You mention in comments below that you found the solution to this problem. Any insights on that claim? I'm stuck for hours on this and I'm very puzzled by it.

Comment: I think I've stopped to use object and I've started to use map with all values instead. But I don't remember it well. I would like to help you, but we've replaced this code later in project, it would be really hard to find it right now. Maybe velocity is not the best option you can chose?

Comment: My problem was that the class was not public. Velocity couldn't see it and didn't throw any error, instead it just ignored all fields typed with that class...

Comment: oh... next time you can ask a question with source code. Community would help you immediately. Anyway glad to hear that you've resolved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your POJO classes are `public`. If your POJO is not public:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Foo {
    private String bar;
    private String baz;
}
```

then:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setBar("lorem");
foo.setBaz("ipsum");

Template template = VELOCITY_ENGINE.getTemplate("/templates/sample.vm", UTF_8.name());
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext(ImmutableMap.<String, Object>of("foo", foo));
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
template.merge(context, writer);
```

will not substitue values of `${foo.bar}` and `${foo.baz}` with `lorem` and `ipsum` respectively.

As soon as I made `Foo` a `public` class, Velocity could render its properties without any issues.

Answer (score -1):

Velocity cannot read private fields. You need to add public getters.

Comment: Im using lombok. Data annotation generates public getters.

Comment: Where did you mention that in your question?! I don't feel like deserving a downvote.

Comment: You should know lombok if you want to talk about Java tools. It is mentioned in pojo class. I can undo this vote but you should remember it next time.

Comment: Or just remove your answer because it is not helpful

Comment: > "You should know lombok if you want to talk about Java tools."
Do you mean that *anyone* speaking of Java tools should know Iombok? I disagree. It is just a tool among an ocean of others. What makes you think that the tools that *you* use should be known by everyone?
> "It is mentioned in pojo class."
You'll have to show me where.
Answers that are not useful for someone may be for someone else. I'm sorry this wasn't your problem, but it's a frequent one (people trying to directly access fields without getters). Just don't accept the answser, if it doesn't please you.

Comment: If you develop Java software, you definitely know lombok. On the other hand if you don't, you should not answer to this question, because there is high probability you won't know the answer.

Comment: Anyway I resolved my problem, by changing template. Velocity somehow loose context somewhere in deep level of html tree. Don't know why.

Comment: I've been developing Java software for years, and it's the first time I hear of it. And if there is no reference to it in the question, I really wonder how I should guess that the question uses a tool which I don't know.

Comment: Start use it! It is a good tool. It generates all the boilerplate. You can remove your answer and you will solve your problem by yourself.

Comment: And if you don't understand annotations, you should ask about them first, then you can post the answer. You did it backward.